# WPF .Net 4.0 MVVM Binding DataGrid Cells To Array Element object

Tags: wpf, arrays, datagrid, binding, matrix

I am Creating a Timesheet application where there is a list of employees together with a list of Codings to assign time to.

I have Created a DataMatrix And I have Got the grid looking Just fine EXCEPT the data entry of the hours

The grid looks something like

```
Work Coding  |   AL | Sick |  Job1 | Job2
____________________________________________
Employee1    |      |      |       |
Employee2    |      |      |       |



public class DataMatrix : IEnumerable
{
    public List<MatrixColumn> Columns { get; set; }
  //  public List<object[]> Rows { get; set; }
    public List<TimesheetDetail[]> Rows { get; set; }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new GenericEnumerator(Rows.ToArray());
    }
}
```

The datagrid ItemsSource is TimesheetArray.

The Issue I am having is when I enter data for Employee1 Job1 the datagrid looks like

```
Work Coding  |   AL | Sick |  Job1 | Job2
____________________________________________
Employee1    |  2   | 2    |  2    |   2
```

Where I Want it looking like

```
Work Coding  |   AL | Sick |  Job1 | Job2
____________________________________________
Employee1    |      |      |   2   |
```

The Data Template looks like

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="TimesheetEntryDetailCellTemplate"
                  DataType="{x:Type data:TimesheetDetail}">
        <Grid>...
              <Label Content="ST" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtStandardTime"
                    Text="{Binding   Path=HoursWorked, ...}"></TextBox>
 </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

With debugging I am getting a TimesheetDetail[] object to bind to

I think I need something like

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Source = TimesheetDetail[ColumnDisplayIndex].HoursWorked}" />
```

Does anyone know how I can get the cell template to bind to the element it is hooked to???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create dynamic binding expression through the code and generating your datagrid columns (AutoGenerateColumns="False" in xaml), apporx. code given below (not compiled):

`public void AddColumns(string[] myHeaderList, List<TimesheetDetail[]> myList) 

{

    for (int i = 0; i < myHeaderList.Length; i++)

    {

        DataGridTemplateColumn gridCol = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

        gridCol.Header = myHeaderList[i];

        gridCol.CellTemplate = 
(DataTemplate)this.Resources["TimesheetEntryDetailCellTemplate"];

        gridCol.Binding = new Binding("[" + i + "].HoursWorked");

        _dataGrid.Columns.Add(gridCol);

    }



}

List<TimesheetDetail[]> myList=...;

_dataGrid.ItemsSource = myList;





In XAML you need to set AutoGenerateColumns to false:

< DataGrid Name="_dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...>`